# How should I initialize my interface in a Kotlin class to pass the data to the main activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my interface:

```
interface ApiResponseListener {
fun didFetch(response: Response<RandomRecipeApiResponse>)
fun didError(msg: String)  }
```

I want to pass the data into this interface like this:

```
val apiResponseListener: ApiResponseListener // here the interface should be initialize and I don't know how
apiResponseListener.didError("test")
apiResponseListener.didFetch(response)
```

Comment: You want to initialize where in activity, in fragment ?

Comment: it is a class. no activity no fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you implement an interface you created, https://pl.kotl.in/K5b9dpU5O.

```kotlin
interface ApiResponseListener {
    fun didFetch(response: Response<RandomRecipeApiResponse>)
    fun didError(msg: String)  
}

fun main() {
    val apiResponseListener = object : ApiResponseListener {
        override fun didFetch(response: Response<RandomRecipeApiResponse>) = Unit
        override fun didError(msg: String) { println(msg) } 
    } 
    
    apiResponseListener.didError("test")
    apiResponseListener.didFetch(Response())
}
```

Read more here:

1. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/interfaces.html
2. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html

###### Suggstion

Prefer the keyword `on` as a prefix in such instances, for example `onSuccess(..)` and `onError(..)`.

Comment: i tried this before. but it returns the data to the class and in the main activity I have no data. 
      override fun didFetch(response: Response<RandomRecipeApiResponse>) {
        Log.d("Main activity", response.toString())
        Toast.makeText(this, " $response",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    override fun didError(msg: String) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "error $msg",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }  there is no action in these functions.

Comment: If what I said doesn't answer your question, please try to clarify the question and provide more info or more of your code. For example, define what do you mean "the class"; there isn't any class mentioned in your question so far.